# Spring Integration WebFlux.outboundGateway is never invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I've a simple flow:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(ARTIFACTORY_INPUT_CHANNEL)
    .handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway(url)
            .expectedResponseType(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Mono<ArtifactorySearchResponse>>() {
            })
            .httpMethod(GET)
            .encodeUri(true))
    .transform(new ArtifactorySearchResponseTransformer())
    .channel(ARTIFACTORY_OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
    .get();
```

And a simple test:

```
outputChannel.subscribe(mockMessageHandler);
inputChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("test"));

verify(mockMessageHandler).handleMessage(argThat(m -> {
    Object payload = m.getPayload();

    return payload instanceof String
            && payload.toString().equals("businesses.20171203.json.gz");
}));
```

that keep failing because the `mockMessageHandler` is never invoked. I've looked, and looked, and looked, but there are exactly zero examples of testing `WebFlux.outboundGateway`. Spring integration does have many examples, but those are almost useless because they

1. Are in XML (yeah, 2005 is calling)
2. Don't cover `WebFlux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, looking in the Spring source code if often times more productive than waiting for help. Turns out, I was missing a few things:

1. The `expectedResponseType` is not supposed to be a reactive publisher, just my DTO/domain object, or some collection of those.
2. The HTTP call was failing but the error didn't show up because I wasn't paying attention to the error channel, and hadn't configured one for my app. I assumed that at least during testing, Spring would log the exceptions, but that wasn't the case. I am considering creating a ticket so that a simple console logging error handler is enabled for tests.
3. I also needed to provide a timeout to allow for the HTTP call to complete. This is done using Mockito [VerificationAfterDelay](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.5/org/mockito/verification/VerificationAfterDelay.html)